# Using "konsole" command to run python script

Tags: python, konsole

I'm trying to, from a command line, open an instance of konsole and run a python script.  I'm trying:

```
konsole -hold -e  'python -i hello.py'
```

The behaviour I'm getting is that a persistent konsole opens, and I am dropped into python, but the script does not run.

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What do I need to do to get the python script to run in the konsole window?

Comment: By the way:

(1) the file "hello.py" has the line

    print("hello from python")

(2) My ultimate goal is to have an "external tool" in Kate that runs the current script.  I'm trying:

    cd "%directory" && konsole -e 'python -i "%filename"'

and I get the same behaviour I described above using the command from a command line.

Comment: I don't use `konsole`, but the `-e` parameter is familiar from `xterm`.  You seem to be using it properly; that works fine with `xterm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsbueno's solution is the correct one. However, as described [here](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-baseapps/konsole/commonissues.html), you can also do something like this ...

`konsole --hold -e /bin/sh -c "python -i hello.py"`

P.S. you'll need to specify --workdir (before the -e arg), or provide the full path to the python script, if it's not always in the initial working dir of konsole. But, you probably already knew that.

Comment: You might want to look more closely at the P.S. in my answer. If you're getting `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` for `hello.py`, it seems likely that konsole has a different initial current working directory than you expect.

Comment: By golly, that did it!  Sorry for not paying attention to the P.S.

Comment: And it worked as an external tool in Kate, which was what I really wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way "konsole" uses the parameters after the `-e` switch - it seems like it simply pass them in a call that does not interpret the space separators as parameter separators.

However, if you don't put your call parameters inside quotes it will work - that is, simply:

```
konsole --hold -e  python -i hello.py
```

(I just tested it here)

Comment: I just tested it from a gnome terminal and it failed.
    ariel.balter@galactus:/nfs/concen/usr2/cslab/home/ariel.balter /Documents$ ls *.py
hello.py

I get the following error in the konsole window that opens:

    /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory