# Change the default input source of sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 for competitive programming. I prefer C++ language. As I have to run my program again and again to check the output, it is easier to write down the input to a file and read input from there. For this I always write some extra lines on my program to read from a file and I comment out those lines before submitting my solution. Can you suggest any way to get rid of this? I am hoping that there is a way to change the default input source by which my program will take input from a file rather than standard input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write conditional code with `freopen` (works with C++ as well). One way supported by [CodeChef](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/5918/taking-inputs-from-input-files-and-test-cases/5919) is

```
#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
#endif

. . . 

cin >> something;   // This will be read from 'in.txt' if ONLINE_JUDGE is not defined
```

The macro `ONLINE_JUDGE` can differ, but [`freopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) is a way to change the input stream source.

**EDIT**: To achieve this in sublime text 3, write a custom build system ([Sublime text 3 - compile program and run in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196077/sublime-text-3-compile-program-and-run-in-terminal)) and use I/O redirector from command line, for instance

```
g++ -Wall -o code code.cpp
./code < in.txt
```

This will read input from the file as if it were stdin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was expecting a solution on sublime text 3 settings though